# how would i remove some portion of <tr><td> from a table in php?

Tags: php, html

this is my table -

```
 <table>
     <tr>
      <td>ABC</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

and I want to remove this one table row:

```
<tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

my expected output is:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>ABC</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

is it possible??please help me

Comment: why would you insert if you want to remove only

Comment: because i inserted it for pdf print

Comment: You would need some DOM parser to do that. Just traverse and remove as needed

Comment: If it's really that simple - which I guess it is not - you can try `tr:nth-of-type(2){display:none}` but that's not php has limited usage.

Comment: @Ihazkode That's not removing it. That's hiding it.

Comment: That actually "removes" it as in get it out of the way for other elements to flow in its place  @icecub, `visibility` or `opacity` will hide it. Check it out with and without the CSS part https://jsfiddle.net/10d9w4kh/

Comment: @Ihazkode It's still hiding it. `display: none;` will hide it and make sure it wont take any space within the result. So yes, it looks like it's removed. But it isn't. The code still exists within the DOM. You can't use CSS to remove something from the DOM. You need a DOM parser for that. Either in PHP or Javascript.

Comment: You're right. I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have tagged your question with the tag php i would recommend using a regular expression.

The pattern `\s*<tr>\s*<td>&nbsp;<\/td>\s*<\/tr>` will find the `tr` with an empty ( ) `td`.

To test and look into the regex you can have a look here: https://regex101.com/r/ax6Xdg/1

Put together this will look something like this:

```
$table = "<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>";

$pattern = "/\s*<tr>\s*<td>&nbsp;<\/td>\s*<\/tr>/";

var_dump( preg_replace( $pattern , "" , $table ) );
```

This will output something very simmilar to this:

```
string '<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
    </tr>
</table>' (length=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using JQuery function `.remove()`. You can look it up [here](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Edit: If you want to locate that specific tag, you can do that by using `.next()`[read here](https://api.jquery.com/next/), `.find()` [read here](https://api.jquery.com/find/),`.parent()`[read here](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), `.children` [read here](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: and how will he select that particular row ?

Comment: There are multiple functions for that too but I believe the question does not demand that. I may add it anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `id` to your table :

```
<table id="tableid">
         <tr>
          <td>ABC</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
```

This script find `&nbsp;`, if found then remove !

```
$('#tableid tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').html()=='&nbsp;') $(this).remove();
});
```

If you want to find some text and then remove then replace `html()` with `text()`

```
$('#tableid tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('td').text()=='ABC') $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<table>
 <tr id="abc>
  <td>ABC</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="remove">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
```

```
<script>
 $('#remove').remove(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the table, add a unique class for the rows you wish to delete. Lets say the class is: `_rowToDelete`, and then using jQuery, remove all the rows that have this class.

In the below example, when you click on the button the rows are being removed, so you can see the changes. But you can do the same on page load if you wish so.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#removeBtn").click(function() {
    $("._rowToDelete").remove() ;
  });
}) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
     <tr>
      <td>ABC 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="_rowToDelete">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>ABC 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="_rowToDelete">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>ABC 3</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="_rowToDelete">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
 
 <a href="javascript:;" id="removeBtn">Remove</a>
```